# Synapse pyspark - execute stored procedure on Azure SQL Database?

Tags: pyspark, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

Ok, I'm trying to adapt some Databricks notebooks (pyspark) to Synapse.  I need to execute stored procedures/DDL/etc. on a regular Azure SQL DB in several places.  In DBX, there's a known, if somewhat clunky, way to accomplish it.  In the init script, you install pyodbc and the linux odbc driver for SQL Server.  Then in your notebook, you make a pyodbc connection for your "executenonquery" procedures, updates, DDL, etc.

In Synapse, pyodbc is one of the default libraries, but I'm not sure how to ensure the sql server odbc driver is installed/available.  I confirmed that neither "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server" nor "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" is installed.  Is there any way to install the driver here?

Comment: It is possible to do this but I would ask why?  If you think about Azure, generally speaking, compute is expensive and storage is cheap.  In your approach, you have two expensive types of compute running at the same time.  A normal pattern for Spark would be to process data and output to parquet, allowing the cluster to shutdown.  Use  something like Azure Data Factory (ADF) for orchestration, eg run a stored proc using the Stored Proc activity, run a Lookup to get data into the pipeline, run a Databricks Notebook activity etc but don't mix

Comment: wBob, vanilla SQL databases are awesome for query responsiveness when you are talking relatively smaller databases.  They're still a great choice for non-huge data warehouses and oltp workloads.

Comment: However, Spark is a great tool for the transformation from staging/data lake to data warehouse.  So... using Spark to do the transformation and pushing to a SQL db with a little bit of cleanup work after the fact can often make a lot of sense.

Comment: As mentioned, you should try and think about things in terms of compute and cost.  Draw out your architecture and colour in compute in red.  Notice how your Spark and SQL compute overlap with your pattern.  Can you think of a pattern where this is less so?  Outputting from Spark to parquet and powering down your Spark cluster is one example.

Comment: What spec is your Spark pool by the way, 10 workers one driver, 64GB RAM for example?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was screwing up the url.  Synapse does include "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" by default.  You can use the same methodology as in Databricks.

Comment: Good, they finally included it by default.  You can also use Scala and JDBC as the Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server is also installed.

Comment: @user2712166 I'm baffled how you got it working ... I've tried same driver in a Synapse notebook, and I also get that error: `InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Comment: I found that I had to use the `pymssql` package instead.  Based on my research, the latest ODBC drivers are not supported on the version of Ubuntu that the python notebooks are running on.  Therefore, this alternative package had to be used which does not have that same dependency.